# Measurable cardinals and well-foundedness

Tags: logic, set-theory, intuition, philosophy

The following is quoted from *What is Mac Lane Missing?* by Mathias.

> The hypothesis that they [measurable cardinals] exist, or the hypothesis that in some inner model there are measurable cardinals may be construed as saying that in certain circumstances the direct limit of well-founded structures is well founded. Other large cardinal axioms may also be interpreted as assertions of this general kind.

Mathias thus argues that measurable cardinals (or even stronger large cardinals) are quite natural, since on the previous page he defines set theory to be the study of well-foundedness. **How exactly are measurable cardinals related to direct limit of well-founded structures?** I suppose the direct limit in iterated ultrapowers is *not* what Mathias is talking about here.

I am mainly interested because the consistency of measurable cardinals is usually justified in extrinsic ways (iterated ultrapower is a beautiful theory, relation to determinacy, etc.) while Mathias seems to give some intrinsic evidence.

Comment: To show neutrality, let me add that Mac Lane wrote a back-to-back article *Is Mathias an ontologist?*

Comment: An ultrapower (not iterated) is also a direct limit. Specifically, the ultrapower of a set $A$ with respect to an ultrafilter $U$ is the direct limit of the system $\langle A^X:X\in U\rangle$, where $A^X$ means the set of functions from $A$ into $X$ and the maps $A^X\to A^Y$ of the direct system are the restriction maps, for $X\supseteq Y$.

Comment: @AndreasBlass Thanks Andreas. By $A^X$ you must have meant functions from $X$ to $A$. Is $A^X$ viewed as the product structure in the same language as $A$, and the direct limit taken in the category of structures where morphisms are (weak) homomorphisms? So Mathias was merely saying "it ought to be possible for the direct limit to be well-founded"? Now this does not seem like a particularly intrinsic argument in favor of measurable cardinals to me

Comment: @Lxm Yes, I should have written "from $X$ to $A$" rather than vice versa.  And I haven't yet been convinced by any argument for the existence of measurable cardinals (in contrast to the consistency of their existence).

Comment: @AndreasBlass: That's a really interesting comment. Can you please elaborate further? In particular, at what point in the large cardinal hierarchy do you start doubting truth (in any sort of platonic sense)?

Comment: @user21820 My doubts start when large-cardinal axioms seem to have some combinatorial aspects apart from mere largeness. So I'm inclined to accept indescribable cardinals (of all the traditional sorts), saying the cumulative hierarchy didn't end just when something interesting was about to happen (because it shouldn't end at all). But I'm not convinced about subtle cardinals existing, even though they're "small" enough to exist in the constructible universe.

Comment: @AndreasBlass: Oh ok. How do you justify "it shouldn't end at all" when it must be 'finished' in order for quantification over the universe to be well-defined so that we can (to some extent) make sense of full replacement/specification via the iterative conception? Can you justify the jump from Bounded ZC to ZFC in a non-circular way? If that is asking too much, given BZC can you philosophically justify at least arithmetical soundness of ZFC?

Comment: @user21820 I'm not convinced that meaningful quantification over entities of some sort requires the existence of a completed (or "finished") totality of all objects of that sort. For example, the commutative law of addition seems to be accepted by finitists, even though it quantifies over all natural numbers and finitists don't accept $\mathbb N$ as a completed totality. Nevertheless, I'm inclined to agree with you that the unrestricted quantification in the ZFC axiom schemas is a weak point in the idea that the axioms are "obviously true".

Comment: @AndreasBlass: There is a difference between the axiom "∀a,b∈ℕ ( a+b = b+a )", which even strict finitists accept, and the belief that *generic* ∀-statements have a (classical) truth-value. The former asserts that a specific ∀-statement is *true* (i.e. commutativity holds for any *given* a,b∈ℕ), and we don't have to be able to get a complete ℕ for this to be so. The latter essentially asserts LEM for ∀-statements, which is not accepted by strict finitists. Predicativists may accept ℕ as complete, but not 'the type of sets'. This is why Π[1,1]-CA is impredicative.

Comment: In other words, from a predicative viewpoint, we may be able to justify truth of "∀x∈S ( Q(x) )" even if S is not a completed type, but we cannot assert "∀x∈S ( Q(x) ) ∨ ∃x∈S ( ¬Q(x) )" for an arbitrary type S.